# Unknown behaviour of React setState

Tags: reactjs

**Case 1**

```
 increaseScoreBy3 () {
     this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
     this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
     this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
    }
```

**Case 2**

```
increaseScoreBy3 () {
 this.setState({score : ++this.state.score});
 this.setState({score : ++this.state.score});
 this.setState({score : ++this.state.score});
}
```

I was reading [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) article and got to know setState function of React is asynchronous. My question is why batching is being done in case 1 and not in case 2 ?
According to the article react will batch the calls to setState so result should be same in both the cases, but it is not happening. 
Please give me a reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

React **may** batch subsequent calls together there is no guarantee for that. There is even an example in the React Docs to that:

> This form of setState() is also asynchronous, and multiple calls during the same cycle may be batched together. For example, if you attempt to increment an item quantity more than once in the same cycle, that will result in the equivalent of:

```
Object.assign(
  previousState,
  {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
  {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
  ...
)
```

> Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next state depends on the previous state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {counter: prevState.quantity + 1};
});
```

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

In general it's a bad idea to rely on asynchronous value changes. This goes for anything async related.

Answer (score 1):

In case 2 you are using a JS operator that modify in place the store value, which is bad.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment

Comment: While this statement is indeed correct (and is great advice to follow!), it is not the correct explanation for why the problem posed in the question is happening. @MuratK 's answer below is the correct answer.

Comment: Let say that the @murat-k answer is the way to go, I totally agree, but still this is happening due to a (dangerous) side effect.

Comment: I am under the impression that multiple sequential calls to setState using the asynchronous syntax are batched arbitrarily and unpredictably at the whim of library (so it can apply heuristics to intelligently optimize performance) regardless of whether the state object is mutated or not. I could be wrong, however.

Comment: In other words, `this.setState({foo:[1, 2, 3]}); this.setState({foo:this.state.foo.map(el => el + 1)});` repeated several times in a row will yield unpredictable results, even though state is not being mutated in place.